# backtest package R extracting returns from object

Tags: r, data-extraction, back-testing

I would like to extract the returns from the backtest package which are according the to the manual stored within a 5 dimensional array called 'results')

This is the backtest package:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/backtest/backtest.pdf

A simple example looks like this:

```
library(backtest)
data(starmine)
bt <- backtest(starmine, in.var = c("smi"),
           ret.var = "ret.0.1.m", date.var = "date",
           id.var = "id", buckets = 10,
           natural = TRUE, by.period = TRUE)
summary(bt)
```

When you run the summary command, it will print out the return series for each decile. I would like to extract those into a dataframe that I can use for further analysis.

Does someone know, how I can access the return series or extract it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bt` object is an object with class `backtest` (which we see from `class(bt)`). The `summary()` function has a method defined for `backtest` objects which only prints the information to the screen. If you try to assign the information via `stuff <- summary(bt)`, the `stuff` object will be `NULL`. To access the data that `summary(bt)` prints to the screen, you should use the *accessor* functions created for that object ( they are described in `?'backtest-class'`). These functions include:

- `means()`
- `counts()`
- `summary()`
- `marginals()`
- `summaryStats()`
- `turnover()`

In order to access the data frame of summary statistics by month printed as the side effect of `summary(bt)`, you can run `summaryStats(bt)`. Please see pages 5-8 of the `backtest` [help files](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/backtest/backtest.pdf) for more information.

Comment: Thank you so much Gabriel, that worked perfectly!!! I was so close...I did indeed try stuff<-summary(bt) and saw the NULL returned, but I did not think of trying summaryStats().